# Inserting a date in a Oracle SP using PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I have the following:

A date but as string (is sended as parameter) called `$fecha` and its value is

> 21/03/2016 10:59:00

and the Oracle SP:

```
$proc = oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, "BEGIN 
                                                BD_SGMR.mr_grabar_marca_carro(
                                                        :p_fecha_marca                                                        
                                                        :estado,
                                                        :mensaje
                                                );
                                            END;");

    oci_bind_by_name($proc,"p_fecha_marca",$fecha);        
    oci_bind_by_name($proc,"estado",$estado,-1,OCI_B_INT ); 
    oci_bind_by_name($proc,"mensaje",$mensaje,200,SQLT_CHR );

    oci_execute($proc);
```

When the procedure is executed I have the next error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  oci_execute(): ORA-01830: la
>   máscara de formato de fecha termina antes de convertir toda la cadena
>   de entrada ORA-06512: en línea 2
>
> Filename:
>   MarcarCarro/MarcarCarro_model.php
>
> Line Number: 172

I don't have find a solution yet.

I appreciate your help

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use `TO_DATE()` always, even in stored routines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date you are passing to Oracle is in a format different from the one Oracle is expecting (the format Oracle is expecting depends on the configuration of your client).
You can specify explicitly the format you are passing using a temporary variable as below.

```
declare 
  input_date date;
BEGIN
 input_date:=to_datE(:p_fecha_marca,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss'); 

 BD_SGMR.mr_grabar_marca_carro(
                                                        input_date,                                                       
                                                        :estado,
                                                        :mensaje
                                                );
 END;
```

To change instead the format oracle is expecting you can issue this statement:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss'
```